# Counting occurences of same array value in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I recently have been building a program where:

1. A user is asked to enter a number that will represent the size of a character array.
2. Then they are asked whether they will want the program to fill the values automatically, or they could press M so they could enter the values manually. They may only enter `a-zA-Z` values, or they will see an error.
3. At the end of the program, I am required to count every duplicate value and display it, for example:

An array of 5 characters consists of `A;A;A;F;G;`

The output should be something like:

```
A - 3

F - 1

G - 1
```

I could do this easily, however, the teacher said I may not use an additional array, but I could make a good use of a few more variables and I also can't use a switch element. I'm totally lost and I can't find a solution. I've added the code down below. I have done everything, but the counting part.

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void main() {
int n, i = 0;
char masiva_izvele, array[100], masiva_burts;
cout << "Enter array size: ";
cin >> n;

clrscr();

cout << "You chose an array of size " << n << endl;
cout << "\nPress M to enter array values manually\nPress A so the program could do it for you.\n\n";

cout << "Your choice (M/A): ";
cin >> masiva_izvele;

if (masiva_izvele == 'M' || masiva_izvele == 'm') {
    clrscr();
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        do {
            cout << "Enter " << i + 1 << " array element: ";
            flushall();
            cin >> masiva_burts;
            cout << endl << int(masiva_burts);
            if (isalpha(masiva_burts)) {
                clrscr();
                array[i] = masiva_burts;

            }
            else {
                clrscr();
                cout << "Unacceptable value, please enter a value from the alphabet!\n\n";
            }
        }
        while (!isalpha(masiva_burts));
    }


}
else if (masiva_izvele == 'A' || masiva_izvele == 'a') {
    clrscr();
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        array[i] = rand() % 25 + 65;

    }
}

clrscr();

cout << "Masivs ir izveidots! \nArray size is " << n <<
    "\nArray consists of following elements:\n\n";

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    cout << array[i] << "\t";

}         



cout << "\n\nPress any key to view the amount of every element in array.";

//The whole thing I miss goes here, teacher said I would need two for loops but I can't seem to find the solution.

getch();

}
```

I would be very thankful for a solution so I could move on and forgive my C++ amateur-ness as I've picked this language up just a few days ago.

Thanks.

EDIT: Edited title to suit the actual problem, as suggested in comments.

Comment: The description is inconsistent. The program, as described, should output duplicates in input data. Chracters `'F'` and `'G'` are not duplicates in your example source data, so they should not appear in the example output! Either you got an improper description of a program (requirements) or an improper set of sample input/output data.

Comment: Suppose the title is wrong, everything else hints to that it should have been "occurrences" instead of "duplicates"...

Comment: @Aconcagua You are right, sorry for being unclear. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is to sort the array, and then iterate over it counting the current letter. When the letter changes (for example from `'A'` to `'F'` as in your example) print the letter and the count. Reset the counter and continue counting the next character.

Comment: ....and don't forget to print the counter when the scan is finished, or you risk to omit the last character form the set.

Answer (score 0):

The main loop should run foreach character in your string.

The secondary loop should run each time the main "passes by" to check if the current letter is in array. If it's there, then ++.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming upper and lower case letters are considered to be equal (otherwise, you need an array twice the size as the one proposed:

```
std::array<unsigned int, 26> counts; //!!!

// get number of characters to read

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < charactersToRead; ++i)
{
    char c; // get a random value or read from console
    // range check, calculate value in range [0; 25] from letter...

    // now the trick: just do not store the value in an array,
    // evaluate it  d i r e c t l y  instead:
    ++counts[c]; 
}

// no  a d d i t i o n a l  array so far...

char c = 'a';
for(auto n : counts)
{
    if(n > 0) // this can happen now...
    {
        // output c and n appropriately! 
    }
    ++c; // only works on character sets without gaps in between [a; z]!
         // special handling required if upper and lower case not considered equal!
}
```

Side note: (see CiaPan's comment to the question): If only true duplicates to be counted, must be `if(n > 1)` within last loop!

Answer (score 0):

Add the array `char chars[52]` and count chars in this array. Then print out chars corresponding to the array, which count is more than 1.

```
std::unordered_map<char, int> chars;
...
char c = ...;
if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')
  ++chars[c];
else if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')
  ++chars[c];
else
  // unexpected char
...
for (const auto p : chars)
  std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << " ";
```

Comment: As denoted in the question, second array is not allowed... We could circumvent this by increasing the initial's array size by 52, though... Kind of cheating?

Comment: @Aconcagua Ok, then I would use `std::unordered_map`

Comment: Depends on how strict the teacher is... unordered map has a *hidden* array inside, to be safe, we'd have to use `std::map`...

Comment: @Aconcagua Since `array[100]` is a big enough we can use the array to count chars in-place applying the algorithm in my previous version.

Comment: Back at my first comment... 52 positions would have to be reserved for the counts then. Maximum array size should be 52 + 255 to prevent overflow...